Do I need to get a second BS or MS to get into Mechanical Engineering?
I have a BA in math, working in an unrelated career field. If I want to get into the mechanical engineering field, is it better to get a second Bachelors in MechE or an MS in MechE? There are programs that will accept me for a MS and make me do a few undergrad prerequisites; however, I'm concerned that the lack of an ABET accredited BS will hold me back in the job market. On the other hand, in my state I would be able to get my PE with just the MS.

duplicated here: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/62285/10902

I have a BS in computer science and an MS in mechanical engineering. No one ever questioned the lack of a BS in ME during interviews for my first job out of my MS. Not even once. As long as your MS is from a decent school, you have a good GPA, you study hard, etc you'll be fine on the job market.
I will say though that I had a lot of the Mech Eng undergrad prereqs before I started my MS. Probably the equivalent of an entire year of classes. So that made most of the MS classes approachable. Without those I probably would have been struggling to keep up
So don't do a second BS for job market concerns. Do do a second BS if you think you might do poorly in MS level ME classes without the proper background

Gonna second this opinion. As long as you know your stuff. (Which honestly would put you ahead of far to many recent ME grads... Remote learning students seem to retain nothing
